# How to produce a more sophisticated pie chart?

Tags: diagrams

I do not know how to make a pie-chart as the one pictured below, which I drew by hand. I tried using "pgf-pie" for that, but it does not really work as I intend. Could you help me?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\newcommand{\QR}[1][n]{\mathcal{QR}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\QNR}[1][n]{\mathcal{QNR}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\QNRP}{\mathcal{QNR}_n^{+1}}
\newcommand{\JNP}{\mathcal{J}_n^{+1}}
\newcommand{\JNM}{\mathcal{J}_n^{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]

\pie [rotate = 90, text=inside, color = {yellow!50, green!50}, scale font]
{75/$\QR[n]$,
    25/$\QNR[n]$}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't.  **Please don't**   Pie charts deliver almost zero information while wasting an inordinate amount of space on the page.   There is never ever a case where a pie chart is the preferred style (excepting the collection of pie-chart jokes)  .   In your example, the meaning of the colors vs. the meaning of the dividing lines is completely unclear, and the labels make it even worse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With plain Ti*k*Z you could do

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\QNR}[1][n]{\mathcal{QNR}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\QNRP}{\mathcal{QNR}_n^{+1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R=2;}]
 \fill[blue!30] (0,R) arc(90:270:R);
 \fill[yellow] (0,R) arc(90:-90:R);
 \draw (0,0) circle[radius=R] (-R,0) node[left] {$+1$} -| (0,R) node[above] {$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$};
 \path (135:R/2) node {$\QNR$} (-90:R/2) node  {$\QNRP$} (0:R) node[right]   {$-1$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `declare function`! I have not been aware for this possibilitiy.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! Note that there is one possible caveat: it is somewhat less straightforward to "undeclare" functions, though possible. That is, if you use several of those in your `tikzpicture`s, try to use them locally in scopes. Never declare them globally outside the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: thank you for info. For purpose as `declare function` is used in your answer so far I use `\def\R{...}`, which also have some limitations.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, sure. You should never define single-letter macros. For instance, `xelatex` defines some of those without telling you. The above was just a remark that one may not overdo it with these `declare function`s, but here it is fine IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

a small variation of @marmot answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\newcommand{\QNR}[1][n]{\mathcal{QNR}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\QNRP}{\mathcal{QNR}_n^{+1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R=16mm;}]
\node[circle, draw, fill=yellow!30, minimum size=2*R,
      label=left: $+1$,
      label=right:$-1$,
      label=$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$] (C) {};
\draw[fill=green!30] (C.south) arc (270:90:R);
\draw (C.west) arc (180:90:R) |- cycle;
\node[below=R/2mm]        {$\QNRP$};
\node[above left=R/2mm]   {$\QNR$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A pstricks solution:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pst-node, pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcommand{\QR}[1][n]{\ensuremath{\mathcal{QR}_{#1}}}
\newcommand{\QNR}[1][n]{\ensuremath{\mathcal{QNR}_{#1}}}
\newcommand{\QNRP}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{QNR}_n^{+1}}}
\newcommand{\JNP}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{J}_n^{+1}}}
\newcommand{\JNM}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{J}_n^{-1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2)(2.5,2.5)
\psChart[userColor={Yellow!50, LightSteelBlue!80, LightSteelBlue!80,Yellow!50,}]{1,1,1,1}{}{2}
\pscircle(0,0){2}
\psline(2;90)(0,0)(2;180)
\rput[B](1.1;140){\QR} \rput[B](1.1;-90){\QNR}
\uput[r](2;0){$-1$}\uput[l](2;180){$+1$}
\uput[u](2;90){$\mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]